# What are options to implement full-duplex connection in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, server, communication, duplex

I have googled quite a lot and the most of the results are suggestions to adapt WebSocket via libraries. Though, as WebSocket was primarily created for browsers to connect to servers, I hoped that iOS has something special and native to implement full-duplex connection for its apps.

So, is my most viable and well-supported option to attach some WebSocket library to the project and align the app code to the realms of WebSocket technology, rather than use native iOS functionality and tweak server code in conformance to the Apple's vision?

What are other ways to make my app receive messages instantly from server when they appear?

Comment: Use push notifications.

Comment: Have you looked at HTTP 2? 
> HTTP/2 allows the server to "push" content, that is, to respond with data for more queries than the client requested

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful projects around that help with low level networking for Obj-C (e.g. [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket))- just add them your project and use a bridging header to use them with Swift.

If you want to dive deeper and gain greater understanding of what's going on with low level networking [Beej's](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) tutorials are great, but but be warned that they are all in C, and that if you go down that route you'll need to worry about threading and queues, which CocoaAsyncSocket will handle for you (or at least make much simpler).

There is also some provision for socket programming in Core Foundation (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI)) This offers an API adapted for Cocoa. (following the standard delegate pattern, and working with `NSRunLoop` etc - so higher level than C sockets, but not as convenient as CocoaAsyncSocket).